# In Flutter, what is the difference between Padding and the SizedBox widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, padding, sizing

Since both are used to add spacing to our screen how do we decide when to use either of them .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. SizedBox creates space between widget to widget only just height and width.
2. Padding is how much an element is away from itself — how much distance an element wants to keep with the elements inside it. They create distance top, bottom, left, and right.
   [image]

[Please checout my answer from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q02le.jpg)

Comment: So SizedBox can be used to add a space between my say appBar and some other widget like column or container ?

Comment: Definitely, you can do it.And you also you can used any kind of widget inside sizedBox with fixed height and width.